# React Native: a basic feature in chat apps, with scrollview

Tags: react-native, scroll, chat, offset

how can i get the scrollView OffsetY if the Scrollbar is available. Like on the start if the view is rendered and if the keyboard is open or closed. In this cases i need the Offset value from the ScrollView.

I want like a baisc chat app, if i enter the chat in should shows me the latest messages at the bottom.
and if the keyboard appears then i should have the same view.

Answer (score 1):

```
profileHeader = () => {
    // you can render your profile view here
    return <View/>;
}

<FlatList
   ref={(c) => { this.flatList = c }}
   data = {this.props.messages}
   keyExtractor={item => item.id}
   inverted={true}
   renderItem = {({item}) => 
    <MessageRow img={item.img}  
    msg = {item.attributes} 
    my_user_id={this.props.my_user_id}/>
   }
   ListHeaderComponent={this.profileHeader} <-- New added -->>
   inverted
/>
```

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#inverted

Comment: Hi is it not possible to make this with a scroll view as well? I have two options one where i need faltlist and one where i have only some data. like a Profile where i can edit. So therefore i need this functionality. I trie with useRef to reference the ScrollView like so: <ScrollView ref={scrollRef}> and then     scrollRef.current.ScrollTo({
      y: 200,
      animated: true
    }) 
to test it. But i get an Error TypeError: scrollRef.current.ScrollTo is not a function do you know why this error happen? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest scroll view for data listing because of the performance on view. For your requirement, you can do is like you can use flat list for your data listing and you can use Flatlist header component to show your profile data on top of the list so you can achieve your desire result with good performance

Comment: do you have a short example how i can do it wth flatlist and header component. do you think for a small profile it cause to problems with scrollview of performance?

Comment: Yes, performance always matters. I have updated my answer please check

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please vote up the answer if you got helped Thanks :-)